# How can I add custom markup to TWiki?

Tags: markup, twiki

At a previous place where I worked a colleague figured out how to configure MediaWiki so that, for example, a string like `#12345` in the wiki markup could be expanded into a hypertext link to ticket 12345 in the ticket system.

I would like to do something similar in TWiki.  I have not yet figured out how, though.  So, if I do, I'll try and answer this question, then. :)

-danny

Answer (score 2):

If the InterwikiPlugin is enabled one can easily add a "wiki link" via the InterWikis node in TWiki.  This is not quite full-fledged custom markup, but implementing a link like `RT:12345` is as easy as adding a table row like this:

```
| RT | https://your-rt-server/Ticket/Display.html?id= | '$page' in RT system |
```

Then, wiki text that contains a string like `RT:12345` would be expanded in to a hyperlink to `https://your-rt-server/Ticket/Display.html?id=12345`

Answer (score 2):

InterWiki links are probably the best way to link to an external site. Otherwise, you can write a TWikiplugin to either register a TWiki TAG handler (ie the %TAG% syntax) or to process the topic text as it goes through the renderer (somewhat slower).

Its not complex Perl, but :)

SvenDowideit